# Ansible: source profile.d in ansible.config

Tags: linux, ansible, devops, ansible-2.x

I'm installing ruby from source and using template to export path. My code looks like this:

```
- name: clone rbenv
  git: repo=git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git dest=/usr/local/rbenv
  become: yes

- template: src=templates/rbenv.sh.j2 dest=/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
  become: true

- name: clone ruby-build repo
  git: repo=git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git dest=~/ruby-build

- name: Install ruby-build
  shell: ./ruby-build/install.sh
  become: yes

- name: install jruby
  shell: . /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh && rbenv install jruby-9.0.5.0
  become: yes
```

I want to use command "rbenv",
this works but in this way I have to source profile with every command.
Is there any way to source profile once in ansible.config file or something else and use it in the whole project without sourcing profile again.

Answer (score 0):

Either add path in .bashrc
or 

`- name: install jruby
  shell: . /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh && rbenv install jruby-9.0.5.0
  become: yes
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash -l` 

/bin/bash -l behaves as login shell